How set Session Timeout Based on Logged In User in ASP.NET Core 8
I have a requirement where based on certain conditions I use to set the session time out after user logs in. It was very easy to do in .NET framework. But I haven't found any solution on how we can achieve this in .NET 8.
In .NET Framework, we use to do something like
HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = some value

But how can we do this in .NET 8.0 ?


I have a requirement where based on certain conditions I use to set
the session time out after user logs in. It was very easy to do in
.NET framework. But I haven't found any solution on how we can achieve
this in .NET 8.

Based on your scenario and description, .NET 8 also can manage session state using  IdleTimeout that indicates how long the session can be idle before its contents are abandoned. It's also very straight-forward and can easily be configured.
If you want to set any specific time to the session state you could configure as following:
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

Note: In IdleTimeout you could set your desired time span.
Once you have added above configuration, after that you have to register session DI within your program.cs file as following:
app.UseSession();

Note:  If you would like to see more example , please refer to this official document.
Update:
Based on your comment, it is possible to have different login lifetimes for different users and this can be achieved by customizing the authentication cookie options based on the user's role, claims.
In order to implement that,  you need to check the user claims while allow users to login and based one user role and claims you could customize authenticationproperties which has ExpiresUtc properties that would modify your users login duration. As you can see below:

Customize your Login code as following:
 var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
 var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
 var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
 {
     IsPersistent = true, // Persist the cookie after the browser is closed
 };


 if (userClaims.Any(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && c.Value == "Admin"))
 {
     authProperties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(12);
 }
 else
 {
     authProperties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
 }

 await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                               new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                               authProperties);

Note: Please refer to this official document for more details.

Thanks for your response, here my requirement is not to set this timeout in program.cs, I want to set different timeout for each user based on their role and other criteria after user login.

Well, thanks for your response, you could achieve that using authenticationproperties  by modifying users role and claims. Please see the updated part.
